# Changing page in cloud9 ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, cloud9

Im looking to change the page in the preview of my application. In the book that im using "railstutorial.org" it states that you can navigate by changing the url, but unfortunately in the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UORKY.png) you can see that the current page is not displayed in the url. How is it possible to change the viewed page.

Answer (score 0):

It's the string in your address bar.

Comment: If you look at my attached image there is no string